# May subclinical Acatalasemia cause premature gray hair in an otherwise healthy human and if so, how is it normally treated?

Tags: nutrition, gastroenterology, genetics, enzyme

It was written in the [current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Catalase&oldid=1072375935) of the Wikipedia article Catalase:

> Low levels of catalase may play a role in the graying process of human hair. Hydrogen peroxide is naturally produced by the body and broken down by catalase. If catalase levels decline, hydrogen peroxide cannot be broken down so well. The hydrogen peroxide interferes with the production of melanin, the pigment that gives hair its color.[54][55]

I say subclinical when comparing this one Acatalasemia single symptom with severe cases of [Acatalasemia as described here](https://medlineplus.gov/genetics/condition/acatalasemia/#resources).

May subclinical Acatalasemia cause premature gray hair in an otherwise healthy human and if so, how is it normally treated?

Comment: This is a difficult one because, if it is sub-clinical, then it is very hard to detect and hence very hard to actually do any studies on without doing a population level survey of the catalase activity in people first, or asking for trial subjects then testing them for activity.